# Can I pass a non-type template argument to an overloaded operator?

Tags: c++, templates, operator-overloading

I would like to add some syntactic sugar to a class by overloading () as a getter method. However, the getter method takes a non-type template argument. Consider a simple test case:

```
#include <iostream>

class Foo
{
public:
  template <int i> void get()
  {
    std::cout << "called get() with " << i << std::endl;
  }
  template <int i> void operator()()
  {
    std::cout << "called overloaded () with " << i << std::endl;
  }
};

int main()
{
  Foo foo;
  foo.get<1>();
  foo.get<2>();
  foo<3>(); // error: no match for ‘operator<’ in ‘foo < 3’
  return 0;
}
```

This compiles and runs as expected if `foo<3>();` is commented out. Does C++ syntax support what I'm trying to do, or should I just give up and stick with a named method for the getter?

Comment: I can't prove it right now but am sure that the only way is `foo.operator()<3>()`, which will probably defeat the purpose.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The syntax you're looking for exists, but you won't like it:

```
foo.operator()<3>();
```

So, stick with the named function.

Answer (score 0):

You could manage by putting the template on the class like so :

```
template<int i>
class Foo
{
    Foo()
    {
        std::cout << "called overloaded () with " << i << std::endl;
    }

    static void Get()
    {
        std::cout << "called get() with " << i << std::endl;
    }
};

int main()
{
    Foo<1>::Get();
    Foo<3>();
    return 0;
}
```

There is however a small loss as you will construct a Foo object when calling the direct () form.

Also, I guess your real-life code has a lot of other things in class Foo, so it will probably not be acceptable to move the template to the class (which can be a significant design change) just to manage this.

EDIT :

Actually since there probably already is an instance of Foo that the OP is using, my whole proposal is dumb. Do not bother.

Comment: I totally agree with you in that it will probably not be acceptable to move the template to the class. Not because it's too much price for accomplishing a little task, but because it just won't accomplish *anything*